# Yii2 advances app rest api pretty url not working

Tags: .htaccess, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, pretty-urls

This is my folder structure

```
-api
   -config
      main.php
   -web
      .htaccess

-backend
   -config
      main.php
   -web
      .htaccess

-frontend
    -config
      main.php
   -web
      .htaccess
```

in my `api/main.php` I enabled pretty url. This is my url manager

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => [
                'user',
                'site'
            ],
            'extraPatterns' => [
                'POST,OPTIONS search' => 'search',
                'GET site/error'=>'error'

            ]
        ],
    ],
],
```

and I configured `my api/web/.htaccess` also

```
RewriteEngine On
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

but for every url I am getting the default `site/index` result. When I remove pretty url code it is working also code it is working in my local,but not working in my server. Do I need to change anything in .htaccess ?
my yii-app url in server is like `www.servername/my-yii-app/api/web`. Any idea?

Comment: If similar code is working different in different machines, I assume that your web-server settings are different. Maybe htaccess is ignored in your server so that it leads to malfunction. You should check AllowOverride if it is set correctly..

Comment: I second this, AllowOverride might not be allowed on the server. Also you can set up an equivalent of .htaccess content in the vhosts files, maybe your server needs that.

Comment: Check is mod_rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: Yes it is enabled